# Cannot create "Hello World" module (and NVIDIA, and VirtualBox)

Tags: debian, kernel, nvidia, drivers

First off, the details.

**BEFORE:** kernel: 3.2.0-2-amd64, nvidia driver: 295.59

**AFTER:** kernel: 3.2.0-3-amd64, nvidia driver: 302.17-3

My Debian wheezy is kept recent at all times. Actually, doing daily `apt-get upgrade -s` got me in this trouble in the first place.

Evidently, after an `apt-get upgrade`, something "broke" on my Debian -- something related to the build ecosystem and/or DKMS itself.

The NVIDIA driver cannot get build by ANY method recommended in the official Wikis. Including the NVIDIA official binary (log snippet from that at one of the updates).

Here's the output of `dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-kernel-dkms`:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-kernel-dkms

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 302.17
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new nvidia-302.17 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.2.0-3-amd64
Building initial module for 3.2.0-3-amd64
Error!  Build of nvidia.ko failed for: 3.2.0-3-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult the make.log in the build directory
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/302.17/build/ for more information.
```

A relevant snippet from `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/302.17/build/make.log` follows.  The problem is **not** in the compilation, I can guarantee that.

```
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/302.17/build/nvidia.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-amd64'
make: Leaving directory `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/302.17/build'
```

And that's it. No explanation of any kind in any other files in the same directory (at least as far as I checked).

Before I ask my questions: I am using nouveau driver now (it's not like I got any choice anyway), but it doesn't work too well for me. I got 3 desktops, constantly playing movies on 1 of them, and being a very busy developer on the other 2. The nouveau driver fails a little bit there (the movies on the second screen get horizontal stripes all the time, the XFCE consoles lag a bit on the scrolling, etc.)

**Questions:**

- Should I change my kernel version? Tried `3.2.0-2-amd64` and `3.2.0-3-amd64`, to no avail. Trying `3.2.0-3-rt-amd64` makes my machine freeze after few minutes of operation, thus I don't dare to install it again.
- Should I change a version of something in my build environment? (As pointed in the updates, it's not just NVIDIA problem, as it turns out).
- Should I assume that my linker is at fault (I am *not* using `gold`, I am using `ld` from the `binutils` package) and if so, what could I do do make the DKMS method finally work? Since the problem does seem to manifest itself on the linkage phase (and MODPOST shows 0 modules).

On a personal note, this disturbs me on a lot deeper level I care to usually admit. I had a **big respect to Debian**, which at the moment is shattered. C'mon, a simple `apt-get upgrade` breaks all open-source kernel drivers compilations / linkages?

Extremely disappointing.

**UPDATE #1:**

I did in fact try to install the official 304.22 NVIDIA drivers, here's the log file. Looks like the linking does indeed fail, does it?

Also, if I try to also enable DKMS integration, I get a message of the sorts that the script cannot determine the current kernel version (text in the 3rd update).

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Sat Jul 21 22:59:30 2012
installer version: 304.22

PATH: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> License accepted.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 304.22.
-> There appears to already be a driver installed on your system (version: 304.22).  As part of installing this driver (version: 304.22), the existing driver will be uninstalled.  Are you sure you want to continue? ('no' will abort installation) (Answer: Yes)
-> Would you like to register the kernel module sources with DKMS? This will allow DKMS to automatically build a new module, if you install a different kernel later. (Answer: No)
-> Performing CC sanity check with CC="gcc-4.6".
-> Performing CC version check with CC="gcc-4.6".
-> Kernel source path: '/lib/modules/3.2.0-3-amd64/source'
-> Kernel output path: '/lib/modules/3.2.0-3-amd64/build'
-> Performing rivafb check.
-> Performing nvidiafb check.
-> Performing Xen check.
-> Cleaning kernel module build directory.
   executing: 'cd ./kernel; make clean'...
-> Building kernel module:
   executing: 'cd ./kernel; make module SYSSRC=/lib/modules/3.2.0-3-amd64/source SYSOUT=/lib/modules/3.2.0-3-amd64/build'...
   NVIDIA: calling KBUILD...
   make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-3-amd64/build \
    KBUILD_SRC=/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common \
    KBUILD_EXTMOD="/tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel" -f /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/Makefile \
    modules
   test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (     \
    echo;                               \
    echo "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
    echo "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
    echo "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
    echo;                               \
    /bin/false)
   mkdir -p /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/.tmp_versions/*
   make -f /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel
     gcc-4.6 -Wp,-MD,/tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/.nv.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated -Iinclude  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/include -include /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/include/linux/kconfig.h   -I/tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Os -m64 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO   -I/tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel -Wall -MD -Wsign-compare -Wno-cast-
   qual -Wno-error -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DNVRM -DNV_VERSION_STRING=\"304.22\" -Wno-unused-function -Wuninitialized -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -UDEBUG -U_DEBUG -DNDEBUG  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(nv)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(nvidia)" -c -o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/.tmp_nv.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv.c
   In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/include/linux/kernel.h:17:0,
                    from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/include/linux/sched.h:55,
                    from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/include/linux/utsname.h:35,
                    from /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv-linux.h:38,
                    from /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv.c:13:
   /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/include/linux/bitops.h: In function ‘hweight_long’:
   /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/include/linux/bitops.h:49:41: warning: signed and unsigned type in conditional expression [-Wsign-compare]
   In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:575:0,
                    from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/include/linux/poll.h:14,
                    from /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv-linux.h:97,
                    from /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv.c:13:
   /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess_64.h: In function ‘copy_from_user’:
   /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess_64.h:53:6: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]

...snipped lots of compile output with the same warning...

     ld -m elf_x86_64   -r -o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nvidia.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv-kernel.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv-acpi.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv-chrdev.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv-cray.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv-gvi.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv-i2c.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv-mempool.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVI
   DIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv-mlock.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv-mmap.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv-p2p.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv-pat.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv-procfs.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv-usermap.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv-vm.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nv-vtophys.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/os-agp.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/os-interface.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/os-mtrr.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/os-registry.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/os-smp.o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/os-usermap.o 
   (cat /dev/null;   echo kernel//tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/nvidia.ko;) > /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/modules.order
   make -f /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/scripts/Makefile.modpost
     scripts/mod/modpost -m  -i /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-amd64/Module.symvers -I /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/Module.symvers  -o /tmp/selfgz10141/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22/kernel/Module.symvers -S -w  -s
   NVIDIA: left KBUILD.
   nvidia.ko failed to build!
   make[1]: *** [module] Error 1
   make: *** [module] Error 2
-> Error.
ERROR: Unable to build the NVIDIA kernel module.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

**UPDATE #2:**

As per the suggestion of *StarNamer*, I did reinstall `linux-headers-3.2.0-3-amd64`. After that was done, DKMS kicked in and tried again to compile the NVIDIA driver. Here's the contents of the file `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/304.22/build/make.log`:

```
DKMS make.log for nvidia-304.22 for kernel 3.2.0-3-amd64 (x86_64)
Sun Jul 22 14:50:58 EEST 2012
If you are using a Linux 2.4 kernel, please make sure
you either have configured kernel sources matching your
kernel or the correct set of kernel headers installed
on your system.

If you are using a Linux 2.6 kernel, please make sure
you have configured kernel sources matching your kernel
installed on your system. If you specified a separate
output directory using either the "KBUILD_OUTPUT" or
the "O" KBUILD parameter, make sure to specify this
directory with the SYSOUT environment variable or with
the equivalent nvidia-installer command line option.

Depending on where and how the kernel sources (or the
kernel headers) were installed, you may need to specify
their location with the SYSSRC environment variable or
the equivalent nvidia-installer command line option.

*** Unable to determine the target kernel version. ***

make: *** [select_makefile] Error 1
```

**UPDATE #3:**

After days and days of googling, I started to wonder if that's NVIDIA's fault at all. Turns out, it's not. I tried to install Virtual Box 4.1 (from the `testing` repo), and I stumbled upon **this again**:

```
# cat /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.18/build/make.log 
DKMS make.log for virtualbox-4.1.18 for kernel 3.2.0-3-amd64 (x86_64)
Tue Jul 24 17:58:57 EEST 2012
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-amd64'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.18/build/built-in.o
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.18/build/vboxdrv/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.18/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
... snipped ...
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.18/build/vboxpci/SUPR0IdcClientComponent.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.18/build/vboxpci/linux/SUPR0IdcClient-linux.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.18/build/vboxpci/vboxpci.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-amd64'
```

And of course, no more details (as already have been said, it does *seem* like a linker problem, but I cannot be sure yet). So this must be more of a Debian / DKMS problem or misconfiguration of some kind. However, I swear I didn't touch anything. I was simply doing daily `apt-get upgrade`-s. Then *something* went not so well, obviously.

**UPDATE #4:**

I did try create a small module as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715259/linux-modpost-does-not-build-anything. Indeed I am still seeing `MODPOST 0 modules`. Here's the output when I put `V=1` in the Makefile:

```
# make
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-3-amd64/build M=/home/dimi/code/hello V=1 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-amd64'
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-amd64 \
    KBUILD_SRC=/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common \
    KBUILD_EXTMOD="/home/dimi/code/hello" -f /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/Makefile \
    modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
    echo;                               \
    echo "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
    echo "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
    echo "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
    echo;                               \
    /bin/false)
mkdir -p /home/dimi/code/hello/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /home/dimi/code/hello/.tmp_versions/*
make -f /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/scripts/Makefile.build obj=/home/dimi/code/hello
   gcc-4.6 -Wp,-MD,/home/dimi/code/hello/.hello.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated -Iinclude  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/include -include /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/include/linux/kconfig.h   -I/home/dimi/code/hello -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Os -m64 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(hello)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(hello)" -c -o /home/dimi/code/hello/.tmp_hello.o /home/dimi/code/hello/hello.c
(cat /dev/null;   echo kernel//home/dimi/code/hello/hello.ko;) > /home/dimi/code/hello/modules.order
make -f /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common/scripts/Makefile.modpost
  scripts/mod/modpost -m  -i /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-amd64/Module.symvers -I /home/dimi/code/hello/Module.symvers  -o /home/dimi/code/hello/Module.symvers -S -w -c -s
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-amd64'
```

And here is what I see when I remove `V=1`:

```
# make
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-3-amd64/build M=/home/dimi/code/hello modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-amd64'
  CC [M]  /home/dimi/code/hello/hello.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-amd64'
```

Comment: Updated the question with a log file.

Comment: The error message says `include/generated/autoconf.h` or `include/config/auto.conf` is missing. On my system, these are in `/usr/src/linix-headers-3.2.0-3-686-pae/`. Have you checked these are in place (your location will presumably be slightly differnt) or tried re-installing the linux header files?

Comment: I did. The new problem is included as UPDATE #2. Thank you for being helpful.

Comment: The log is saying that either the kernel sources or headers are not configured correctly (I've looked at the `nvidia-installer` script and the reference to 2.6 actually refers to 2.6 or 3). It's indicating it may need the kernel source (package `linux-source`) as well as the headers.

Comment: I downloaded the Beta 304.22 run file (x86 version) and tried it on my system. It also fails at the dkms build stage but works if I don't add it to dkms. Since the 295.59 version doesn't support dkms and 304.22 is Beta, I suspect there may be a bug in the script. (Nore: I reverted to 295.59 because nvidia-settings in 304.22 doesn't support adjusting overscan, which I need).

Comment: So your recomendation is: try with the NVIDIA 295.59 binary? If so, I will do that at some time today, thanks.

Comment: I agree with the edit that this looks like a DKMS problem. I am not sure if it's specific to NVIDA - I've never had a problem with VirtualBox's DKMS setup. I think you'd probably be OK with the 304.22 driver if you didn't request it to add the DKMS functionality.

Comment: I just looked more closely at your VirtualBox make.log and I can't actually see an error there, apart from the fact it built zero modules! One of the references I found to this was here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715259/linux-modpost-does-not-build-anything) where it was suggested that the kernel configuration was broken, but it was not resolved; the problem just 'went away'. I know you reinstalled linux-headers, but it might be worth trying to purge this package (and perhaps dkms and virtualbox-dkms) and then reinstall tehm all.

Comment: Thank you for continued support. I already did that -- guess it would have been too easy if it worked. My epic Google hunt goes on in the meantime...

Comment: See update #4 please. Sadly I am no further than the guy who asked the question you linked (yet).

Comment: Update #4 is still getting the same error as Update #1 (missing `include/generated/autoconf.h` or `include/config/auto.conf`). Are you sure the right version of `linux-headers` (and possibly `linux-sources`) are installed? They should be under `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)`.

Comment: I think you are mistaken -- the `V=1` causes the script to be overly verbosive: it this case, it prints the shell code it invokes. If you read through it again, you will see that it is not actually issuing the error. Also, this is not shown when `V=1` is skipped, which proves there is no error.

Comment: My mistake. In fact, when I look carefully (and not late at night) it's not clear what the error was in #update 1. The warnings should not have stopped make and there's no error report from ld.

Comment: See the comments in Craig Sanders answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

Simple as that: `/root/.bashrc` had this inside:

```
 export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'
```

Changed it to:

```
 export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=never'
```

...and restarted the root shell (*of course*; do not omit this step). Everything started working again. Both NVIDIA and VirtualBox kernel modules built from the first try. I am so happy! :-)

Then again though, I am slighly disappointed by the kernel build tools. They should know better and pass `--color=never` everywhere they use `grep`; or rather, store the old value of `GREP_OPTIONS`, override it for the lifetime of the building process, then restore it.

I am hopeful that my epic one-week battle with this problem will prove valuable both to the community and the kernel build tools developers.

A very warm thanks to the people who were with me and tried to help.

(All credits go here: http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-4156366.html#4156366)

Comment: Congratulations on finding the solution. I'd think that qualifies as a bug in the kernel build tools as it really should not break just because someone likes color output from grep!

Comment: Nice find.  Frustrating and annoying, too.  I think it's the kind of thing that never gets tested, though, because most people who want colour ouput use `--colour=auto` so that ESC codes don't pollute the output when it's being piped or redirected.  On the few occasions you might want colourised output piped (e.g. when piping to `less -r`) you can specify `--colour` on the command line.

Comment: Only trouble here, I got no idea whatsoever who must I show this page, so that the Linux kernel build tools team notices and maybe does something about it.

Comment: @dimitko, you should try the [kernel bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried purging and reinstalling dkms?

You could use `apt-get purge dkms` and that will also purge all the packages that depend on it, so you'll have to reinstall them afterwards.

If you don't want the dependant packages purged too, you could use dpkg:

`dpkg --purge --force-depends dkms`

reinstall with the usual: `apt-get install dkms`

FWIW, I have two machines here (running debian sid) with kernel linux-image-3.2.0-3-amd64 and the nvidia-kernel-dkms 302.17-3 and related packages installed.  The dkms module compiled without a problem.  A third machine (my main desktop) is still running nvidia-kernel-dkms 295.53-1, mostly because I don't want to have to logout.

BTW, you mentioned purging and re-installing the various nvidia packages with aptitude.  There are several nvidia packages that don't have nvidia in the package name.  Here's the solution I came up with to hold/unhold nvidia pkgs (I usually only want to upgrade nvidia pkgs when I'm willing/able to log out of my current X session...and after a few unpleasant surprises with new nvidia versions, I like to test them on my least-important machine first):

(note: you'll need my dlocate package installed to run this)

```
$ cat /usr/local/sbin/hold-nvidia.sh 
#! /bin/bash

PKGS=$(dlocate -l nvidia cuda vdpau | awk '/^[hi]i/ {print $2}' | sed -e 's/:.*//')

echo dpkg-hold $PKGS
dpkg-hold $PKGS
```

There's a nearly identical one for un-holding packages (runs `dpkg-unhold` instead of `dpkg-hold`), and it would be trivial to make it run `dpkg --purge` or `apt-get purge` instead.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't try to purge dkms itself yet -- I am gonna do it after I am done working for the day. I got another question for you though -- did you read my edits on trying to create a "hello world" module? The part where no .ko file ever gets created? Do you got any idea on how should I remedy this? (`modpost` is inside the `linux-kbuild-3.2` package btw.)

Comment: sorry, kind of skipped over it in a tl;dr fashion :).  I did notice just now in UPDATE #1 that you have several non-standard directories in your PATH...is there any chance there's a conflicting binary/script in one of those dirs?  have you tried setting a "standard" PATH (just the usual system dirs) before building the dkms module?

Comment: You could be right. I got RVM, and it's infamous for overriding important things in one's environment. Just finished my 18-hour freelancing "working day", gonna crash now, but both your suggestions will be tried, first thing when I get up. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly, no joy. Removed RVM from my `.bashrc` files (both the root and the regular user), restarted the console, then purged `dkms` (which naturally purged `nvidia-kernel-dkms` and `virtualbox-dkms`). Then I did `apt-get clean` (even though `debsubs` didn't report problems), then I did reinstall them. Nothing changed.

Can we try to solve the issue in Update #4 btw? (I believe it's the root of the problem.) I got a tiny "hello world" module, and even it doesn't get a .ko file  built. You got any idea on this?

Comment: have you seen http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=635317 ? different error message, but the problem was solved by upgrading to the make package from experimental.  what version of make is installed?  I have 3.81-8.2 from sid.  experimental has 3.82-1.

Comment: sorry, ignore that.  i read it wrong.  the make from experimental causes the problem.  reverting fixes it.

Comment: My `make` is `3.81-8.2` at the moment (that version is both in wheezy and sid). I am gonna try the patches found in the linked bug (and a link found in there as well) and report back.

Comment: No luck. I am browsing `modpost.c` and `Makefile.modpost` in the hopes I can get some sort of reason... will appreciate every clue you can give me in the meantime.

Comment: what does `dkms status` say?  have you got both linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common and linux-headers-3.2.0-3-amd64 installed? have you tried `dkms build -m nvidia -v 302.17 -k 3.2.0-3-amd64 && dkms install -m nvidia -v 302.17 -k 3.2.0-3-amd64`

Comment: also, what does `ld -v` say?  if it says 'GNU gold' rather than 'GNU ld' that could be the problem.  there's a comment in the nvidia src Makefile that says `# avoid ld.gold, see #626279
LD=ld.bfd
`

Comment: `GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.22` -- this is what I get. BTW, after some inspection of `Makefile.modpost`, I established that the phase where `.mod.c` file(s) must be generated, well, they don't. So it's no wonder .ko file is not built. Reference: `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-3-amd64/scripts/Makefile.modpost`. Namely, step #3 is at fault. Something's wrong and and nobody tells me what it is, even when I issue `make V=1`.

Comment: (1) `dkms status` gives this: `nvidia, 302.17: added`. (2) Yes, I have both packages since the start of my tries. (3) The command I pastes was already tried, gives the same every time (see Update #3, same happens with NVIDIA as with VirtualBox). Simply `MODPOST 0 modules` and that's all. :-( See my previous comment for some would-be pinpointing I did.

Comment: Even though I solved the problem myself, I am giving the bounty to you. Thanks for your efforts, they are appreciated. :)

Comment: thank you.  i'd run out of ideas and the --color thing would never have occurred to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is no good:

```
PATH: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:\
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:\
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:\
    /usr/local/rvm/bin:\
    /usr/local/sbin:\
    /usr/local/bin:\
    /usr/sbin:\
    /usr/bin:\
    /sbin:\
    /bin
```

I am willing to bet that in at least a few of those directories you had *`$PATH`ed* ahead of *`/bin`* and *`/sbin`* - especially the *`ruby`* ones - you had common shell app wrapper scripts for colorizing output. Maybe you even had similar configuration applied in *`/etc/skel`* in which case not even *`/bin/env -i grep`* could have saved you from yourself.

This is why people compile in *`chroot.`*

P.S. I'm only so critical because I had to learn the same lesson the same way a couple years back. You probably would not have needed the *`=never`* if your *`$PATH`* was clean. Also, you can just use *[`--color=auto`](http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html)* in which case the terminal escapes are only used if *`grep`'s`stdout`* is a terminal - in other words - not in a *`|pipe`* to *`gcc.`*

Or, even better, instead of setting an inflexible shell *`alias`* with:

```
alias grep=grep\ --color=anything
```

You could take advantage of *[`grep`'s`$ENV`](http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html)* setting:

```
GREP_COLOR=auto
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and the advice. While the original problem was that I was forcing grep to always colorize its output, I am tkaing a note to compile in chroot from here on, indeed.

Comment: @dimitko Yeah. It was a little on the jerk side, though, maybe. I think I may have tempered it a bit in postscript and added a little more info.

Comment: I agree, and don't worry about it, I didn't take offense. ;) I felt incredibly stupid after discovering the "solution". Even if I don't use the `GREP_COLOR` environment variable, I believe grep assumes auto-colorizing by default anyway. So in the end, I just shouldn't have meddled with it. :D Anyway though, and again, experimenting in chroot definitely works better, can't deny it.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Debian Wheezy (32-bit) with NVIDIA drivers. I also recently tried the DKMS 320.17 version, but reverted to the 'Official' NVIDIA build (295.59), not because it failed to install, but because it doesn't include the `nvidia-settings` program and I need to reset the overscan on my HD TV (secondary monitor).

Having said that, you shouldn't need to link `/usr/bin/gcc` to gcc-4.6 to run the older version. I just executed `CC=gcc-4.6` before running the 'Official' 295.59 installation after I purged all the nvidia stuff that `apt-get` had installed.

Wheezy is still the **testing** version, so it's possible you've hit a bug that hasn't been properly tested in the 64-bit build. As I said, my 32-bit upgrade showed no problem apart from missing functionality. You might want to look at logging a bug report if you are sure everything's OK on your system.

My recommendation would be to revert to the 295.59 'Official' version (either using your link or defining CC to use the right version of `gcc`) and then to wait for an update to the nvidia-kernel-dkms module (or until Wheezy is release as **stable**).

Of course, if you check [here](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=wheezy&keywords=nvidia-kernel-dkms) you'll see that the code is **Non-free** anyway, so it's probably using a pre-release version of the 'Official' binary which would simply add to the possibilities of problems.

Comment: I tried downgrading. Sadly absolutely the same problem appeared. I forgot to include that in the original post, sorry about that. But after purging everything that apt-get installed (and I did log that and then properly removed it), and issued the apt-get install (with the 295.59 version), I hit exactly the same problem. It's why I said "evidently something broke", as unclear as this sounds.

Comment: I actually downloaded the file `NVIDIA-Linux-x86-295.59.run` from the NVIDIA website (there's probably an Amd64 version) and built it that way.This is what I assumed you meant by the 'official' version. I also went through all installed packages with `nvidia` in the name (using `aptitude`) and purged everything to avoid problems. I'm also running kernel 3.2.0-3 so don't think a kernel downgrade would help.

Comment: Well, that would be my last resort, to be fair. I hate re-running such procedures every time I get an update to the kernel. That's what DKMS is for. Anyway, I believe my case is some vague linker problem, which I hoped this site can help with. :-(