# Compiling kernel but doesn't build kernel modules

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, kernel-modules, cross-compilation

I am trying to compile a linux-sunxi kernel for my Banana pi.

[Using this link: http://sunxi.org/Linux_Kernel#Compilation](http://sunxi.org/Linux_Kernel#Compilation)

Unfortunately I am getting the following message at the bottom when I am trying to compile the uImage and modules. (Step: `make -j4 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- uImage modules`)

```
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules
```

Does anyone have any clue how to fix this? I do have a configuration where loadable modules are enabled and for example I have the hid-multitouch enabled.

When executing `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- INSTALL_MOD_PATH=output modules_install` I get:

```
DEPMOD  3.19.0-rc6-45640-g77f18db
```

With no build modules in it at all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem! After googling around for a good while, it finally turned out (in my case) that the kernel build toolchain is very picky about some `env` options, as pointed out [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44167/18455).

Here, in my `~/.bashrc` I had `export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'` and that seems to be causing problem with the module script generation.

So changing it to `export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'` or `export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=never'` **AND** logging out/in solved the problem!

When `GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'` used:

```
$ make clean modules SUBDIRS=drivers/staging/usbip
  CLEAN   drivers/staging/usbip/.tmp_versions
  CLEAN   drivers/staging/usbip/Module.symvers
  LD      drivers/staging/usbip/built-in.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/usbip_common.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/usbip_event.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/stub_dev.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/stub_main.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/stub_rx.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/stub_tx.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/vhci_sysfs.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/vhci_tx.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/vhci_rx.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/vhci_hcd.o
  LD [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/usbip-core.o
  LD [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/vhci-hcd.o
  LD [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/usbip-host.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules
```

Changing to `GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'` and logging out/in:

```
$ make clean modules SUBDIRS=drivers/staging/usbip
  CLEAN   drivers/staging/usbip/.tmp_versions
  CLEAN   drivers/staging/usbip/Module.symvers
  LD      drivers/staging/usbip/built-in.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/usbip_common.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/usbip_event.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/stub_dev.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/stub_main.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/stub_rx.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/stub_tx.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/vhci_sysfs.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/vhci_tx.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/vhci_rx.o
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/vhci_hcd.o
  LD [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/usbip-core.o
  LD [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/vhci-hcd.o
  LD [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/usbip-host.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 3 modules
  CC      drivers/staging/usbip/usbip-core.mod.o
  LD [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/usbip-core.ko
  CC      drivers/staging/usbip/usbip-host.mod.o
  LD [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/usbip-host.ko
  CC      drivers/staging/usbip/vhci-hcd.mod.o
  LD [M]  drivers/staging/usbip/vhci-hcd.ko
```

Mad!